# Broken scroll functions when trying to adjust content while scrolling

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am trying to create a page with L-shaped grids.  I got the layout down by creating 2 x 2 grids and each grid uses a 0 width div as a spacer to push another floated div to void out the space where I don't want text to appear. I am having a problem now trying to be able to scroll the text and adjust the position of the floated void div by adjusting the height of the spacer div.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tr').on('scroll', function (e) {
        // Some extra values for troubleshooting
        let sH = $('#tr').prop('scrollHeight');
        let sT = $('#tr').prop('scrollTop');

        let poH = $('#tr').outerHeight();
        let poHt = $('#tr').outerHeight(true);
        let ph = $('#tr').height();

        let soH = $('#trs').outerHeight();
        let soHt = $('#trs').outerHeight(true);
        let sh = $('#trs').height();

        let voH = $('#trv').outerHeight();
        let voHt = $('#trv').outerHeight(true);
        let vh = $('#trv').height();
        let vo = $('#trv').offset().top;
        // console.log(`sH: ${sH}, \nsT: ${sT}, \npoH: ${poH}, \nph: ${ph}, \nsoH: ${soH}, \nsh: ${sh}, \nvoH: ${voH}, \nvh: ${vh}, \nvo: ${vo} `);


        /*
        Method #1 - Trying to change the vertical spacer height to increment with same value as scroll distance.
        Problem - Once scroll starts, it does not stop until it reaches the end.  Once it reaches the end it also
        seems to be  stuck in a loop...I think this it because  the parent heigh changes as content adjusts...
        But I'll worry about that after I figure out how to get the scrolling to stop.
        */

        let x = ph / 2 + sT;
        // console.log(`x: ${x}`);
        $('#trs').height(x);


        /*
        Method 2 - Keep incrementing the spacer height of the spacer until the height of the void div is in the desired position.
        Problem - It too gets stuck scrolling all the way to the bottom once the scroll is started.  It also seems to hang that
        once the scroll is started, the console doesn't spit out all the content for several seconds, and I can refresh the page
        for a while.  I tried putting in some counter and breaking the loop if it runs too long, but that does not seem to help.
        */

        // let c = 0;
        // let margin = 16;
        // let y = ph / 2 + margin;
        // // console.log(`y: ${y}`);
        // while (vo < y) {
        //     $('#trs').height($('#trs').height() + 1);
        //     vo = $('#trv').offset().top;
        //     c++;
        // //     console.log(`+vo: ${vo}, c: ${c}`);
        //     if (c === 100) {
        // //         console.log("!-"); break;
        //     }
        // }

        // let z = ph / 2 + margin;
        // // console.log(`z: ${z}`);
        // while (vo > z) {
        //     $('#trs').height($('#trs').height() - 1);
        //     vo = $('#trv').offset().top;
        //     c++;
        // //     console.log(`-vo: ${vo}, c: ${c}`);
        //     if (c === 100) {
        // //         console.log("!-"); break;
        //     }
        // }              


    })
});
```

```css
* {
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    height: calc(100vh - 8px);
    margin: -4px;
}


#tl {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 3;
    background-color: red;
    margin: -4px;
}

#tr {
    grid-area: 1 / 3 / 3 / 5;
    background-color: purple;
    margin: -4px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#bl {
    grid-area: 3 / 1 / 5 / 3;
    background-color: orange;
    margin: -4px;
}

#br {
    grid-area: 3 / 3 / 5 / 5;
    background-color: green;
    margin: -4px;
}

#c {
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 4 / 4;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    /* display: none; */
}


.grid-container * {
    border: 8px solid white;
    padding: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.vert-space-top {
    width: 0px;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
}

.vert-space-bottom {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0%;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
}

.void {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
    border: none;
}

.right {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}

.left {
    clear: right;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS L-Shaped Grid With Wrap-Around</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div id="tl">
            <div class="vert-space-top left"></div>
            <div class="void left"></div>
            CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped
            grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS
            p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped
            grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped
            grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS
            p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped
            grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped
            grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS
            p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped
            grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped
            grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS
            p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped
            grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped
            grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS
            p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped
            grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid. CSS p-shaped grid.<br>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
            <div id="trs" class="vert-space-top right"></div>
            <div id="trv" class="void right"></div>
            CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS
            q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS
            q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS
            q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS
            q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS
            q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS
            q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS
            q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS
            q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS
            q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS
            q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS
            q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS
            q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped
            grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid. CSS q-shaped grid.<br>
        </div>
        <div id="bl">
            <div id="bls" class="vert-space-bottom left"></div>
            <div class="void left"></div>
            CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped
            grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS
            b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped
            grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped
            grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS
            b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped
            grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped
            grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS
            b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped
            grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped
            grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS
            b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped
            grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped
            grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS
            b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped
            grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid. CSS b-shaped grid.<br>
        </div>
        <div id="br">
            <div id="brs" class="vert-space-bottom right"></div>
            <div class="void right"></div>
            CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped
            grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS
            d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped
            grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped
            grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS
            d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped
            grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped
            grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS
            d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped
            grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped
            grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS
            d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped
            grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped
            grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS
            d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped
            grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid. CSS d-shaped grid.<br>
        </div>
        <div id="c">
            CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped
            grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS
            o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped
            grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped
            grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS
            o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped
            grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped
            grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS
            o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped
            grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped
            grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS
            o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped
            grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped
            grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS
            o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped
            grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped
            grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS
            o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped
            grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped
            grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS
            o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped
            grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid.<br>
            CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped
            grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS
            o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped
            grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid. CSS o-shaped grid.<br>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Trying to add scrolling staring with the top right box (because the ones on the left are going to require some extra magic to get the scroll bars on the left hand side), I have 2 methods in the code I am trying to get to work - you have comment out the one & uncomment to other to get the other to run.  But the problems I am having with either method are:

Method #1 - Trying to change the vertical spacer height to increment with same value as scroll distance.
Problem - Once scroll starts, it does not stop until it reaches the end.  Once it reaches the end it also          seems to be  stuck in a loop...I think this it because  the parent height changes as content adjusts... But I'll worry about that after I figure out how to get the scrolling to stop.

(Actually, when running the code in the snippet I added here, method 1 seems to be working as desired when using the mouse wheel to scroll, but still not when trying to click/drag the scrollbar. And neither work as it's own stand alone page)

Method 2 - Keep incrementing the spacer height of the spacer until the height of the void div is in the desired position.
Problem - It too gets stuck scrolling all the way to the bottom once the scroll is started.  It also seems to hang that once the scroll is started, the console doesn't spit out all the content for several seconds, and I can refresh the page for a while.  I tried putting in some counter and breaking the loop if it runs too long, but that does not seem to help.

Can I get any help getting a working function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found to resolve the bugs I was having I had to change the width of the spacer divs from

```
width: 1px;
```

The function I came up with otherwise works fine after this change.

Good Job!